# magento escape string for JavaScript part 2

Tags: php, magento, escaping, json

This is a follow up on
[magento escape string for javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771036/magento-escape-string-for-javascript)

where I accepted @AlanStorm suggestion to use json_encode to escape string literals.

But I now have a new problem with this solution.

when trying to escape a URL that has /'s in it to be rendered as a string literal for JavaScript json_encode seems to add redundant \'s in front of the /'s.

Any new suggestions here?

solutions should take a string variable and return a string that would properly be evaluated to a string literal in JavaScript. (I don't care if its surrounded with single or double quotes - although I prefer single quotes. And it must also support newlines in the string.)

Thanks

Comment: some more info:
how comes `<?php $v=array('a'=>'/');echo json_encode($v); ?>`
results in `{"a":"\/"}`  ?
is this not simply a bug in json_encode ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> some more info: how comes '/');echo
>   json_encode($v); ?> results in
>   {"a":"\/"} ?

Details can be found here http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49366

work around for this issue:

```
str_replace('\\/', '/', $jsonEncoded);
```

for your issue you can do something like

```
$jsonDecoded = str_replace(array("\\/", "/'s"), array("/", "/\'s"), $jsonEncoded);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I don't like the idea of replace in every place I need to do this. but it can be used inside a wrapper. alst at the end of the link you provided it says that there is a JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES option to json_encode, but I am not sure what version it is for. I think I will go with a Wrapper of my own for this.

Answer (score 2):

When I check the [JSON format](https://www.json.org/) I see that solidi are allowed to be escaped so `json_encode` is in fact working correctly.

[image: JSON String]
<sub>(source: [json.org](http://www.json.org/string.gif))</sub>

The bug link posted by satrun77 even says "It's not incorrect to escape slashes."

If you're adamant to do without and (in this case) are certain to be working with a string you can use a hack like this:

```
echo '["', addslashes($string), '"]';
```

Obviously that doesn't help for more complicated structures but as luck has it, you are using Magento which is highly modifiable. Copy `lib/Zend/Json/Encoder.php` to `app/core/local/Zend/Json/Encoder.php` (which forms an override) and fix it's `_encodeString` method.

Comment: I accept, it is not a bug in the json_encode.
So obviously I should NOT fix json_encode - as they say, if it ain't broke, son't fix it...
so if this is the case then using json_encode is not what I need, so its back to square one, what should I use to output a properly escaped javascript literal string ? Will I have to write my own toJSStringLiteral() eventually?

Comment: It's a tricky issue. I guess if we were to be completely objective then the bug lies with JSON decoders that cannot handle the escape character - those are the ones that should be fixed.

Comment: that would have been true if I wanted to use this for a jason object. all I need is to render a string literal for javascript. It is actually not JSON, maybe JSON related at best

Comment: Then `addslashes()` is your friend. ;-)